# Implementation details in Set properties in c# interfaces

Tags: c#

I am new to c#. I have gone through interfaces and got to know that only properties and methods are allowed inside interfaces as they shouldn't contain any implementation details.Also I got to know that even though properties are allowed in c# they don't generate a backing field unlike in class. Whats bothering me is c# compiler is allowing me to write this interface :

```
  interface IPrinter {
    int printCount { 
      get { 
        return printCount; 
      }
      set { 
        Console.WriteLine("Your text:"); 
      }
    }
  }
```

I can even execute it as well. Can someone please correct my understanding on why c# is not restricting  my implementation in interfaces?

Comment: what is your C# version ?! C# 8.0 ?!

Comment: In C# 8 and forward, you can actually have default (method) implementation on interfaces.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko In C# 8.0, They can. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods

Comment: @Tvde1. Thank you , but it will deviate the contract defined and may prone to change .is it legal ?

Comment: The motiviation is to be able to change the contract without breaking the implementation.

Comment: @Tvde1 If posible can you please share a simple example / use case where we need to change the contract  with this feature. I mean it will affect the other party that uses it right

Answer (score 2):

You refer to a feature from C#8: [default-implementaion of interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods), which of now is just a *draft*. With this feature you´re able to have an implementaion within the interface itself, without the need to actually create a concrete class. From my understanding that boils down to something similar to an abstract base-class that has the name of the interface, though.

As of the specs for this feature:

> Interfaces may not contain instance state. While static fields are now permitted, instance fields are not permitted in interfaces.

In your case you don´t have any **state**. The `printCount` is a **property**, not a **field**. It particular your property does not have any backing-field, all it does is to call a `static` method (and an infinit recursion in your getter leading to a `StackOverlowException` at runtime, btw.).

So unless you don´t introduce some kind of state into an interface - which by the specs is by referring to an **instance-field** - you can anything you want within the default-implementation.

Comment: Agree on Get but in Set I am still able to perform some implementation.

Comment: @ganesh310 In get as well. The point here is just that there´s no backing-field included, because it simply does not exist for **non-auto-properties**. But even **if** it existed, it would have some cryptinc random name similar to `<>_Type_backingField`, but definitly not `proeprtyCount` (don´t know the exact syntax, anyway it´s an implementaion-detail of the language).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Can you please share your view on when to use default implementation in interfaces in c#

Comment: @ganesh310 What do you mean by "my view on"? We won´t comment MS´ features-decisions here.

Comment: I meant a practical use case would be helpful for beginners like me

Comment: I don't think his question is about the possible `StackOverflowException` but about writing `Console.WriteLine` and other implementation in an interface.

Comment: @Tvde1 I don´t get it. Surely you can write to console without the default implementation. That doesn´t break anything (except the side-affect of introducing a dependency statically).